# How to sort array of object inside foreach? (Updated)

Tags: php

bookedTimes are already showing my problem is how can I sort the items from the highest booked to the lest booked. Any answers and suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="row">

    @if(!empty($Service) && count($Service))

    @foreach($Service['result'] as $value)

    @foreach($value as $val)
    <?php
        $arrange = array($val['bookedTimes']);
        arsort($arrange);
        foreach($arrange as $x => $x_value) {
            echo $x_value;
        }
    ?>

    @endforeach
    @endforeach
    @else
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12"><h4>Data Not Found! </h4> </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

This is the booked time data that is need to be in Descending Order

[image]

Comment: You can use `orderBy` in your controller and then pass it to your view.

Comment: @dqureshiumar How can I make it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place an `usort` function after the first iteration's start point and you will get the sorted `bookTimes` in the second iteration.

```
<div class="row">

@if(!empty($Service) && count($Service))

@foreach($Service['result'] as $value)

<?php

usort( $value, function ( $a, $b )
{
//$b should come first as you want to sort in descending order
return $b['bookedTimes'] <=> $a['bookedTimes'];
});
?>

@foreach($value as $val)


@endforeach
@endforeach
@else
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12"><h4>Data Not Found! </h4> </div>
@endif
</div>
```

Comment: Hi I got this error: Illegal string offset 'booked-times'

Comment: Hi im still getting this error. >Illegal string offset 'bookedTimes'

Comment: you have to change the `booked-times` string to `name` as name index is holding the values , replace your cmp function by mine

Comment: I also try name but it still kicking the same error. But I want booked-times to sort from highest to lest not by name

Comment: please , share your errors in post for which you are getting error in illegal offset

Comment: okay got it , you are sorting using the book-times not names .sorry for getting wrong. okay why don't sort from the eloquent using `orderBy`

Comment: I don't know how

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223801/discussion-between-al-amin-and-frustrated-dev).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223804/discussion-between-frustrated-dev-and-al-amin).

Answer (score 1):

arsort sorts an array into reverse order. It has two parameters. The second says how the elements of the array should be interpreted.

To ensure that you get a numeric sort you can use:

```
arsort($arrange, SORT_NUMERIC)
```